# Capybara selenium_chrome going to example.com instead of localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I am setting up Cucumber tests in a Rails project.  Everything works fine when I use the default driver; but, when I try to use the `:selenium_chrome` driver, the browser tries to load `example.com` instead of the local Rails server.  Any idea what I'm missing?

My steps look like this:

```
Before do |scenario|
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
end

When(/^I visit the posts page$/) do
  visit posts_url
end
```

When I run the features, I can see that the rails server gets launched:

```
Using the default profile...
Feature: Posts

Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:62056
```

But, the Chrome window that pops up is attempting to access `http://www.example.com/posts` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:62056/posts`

Am I missing a configuration step somewhere?

On a related note: If I want to run all my tests using Selenium, should I have to put the `Capybara.current_driver` line in a `Before` block?  I tried just adding it to `features/support/env.rb`, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I have Chrome 73.0.3683.86 and Rails 5.2.2 running on MacOS 10.14.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `:selenium_chrome` as the default driver, you can set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome`.

As to the `example.com` issue that's because you're visiting `posts_url` and have your Rails default hostname set to be `example.com` in your test environment. You can either visit `posts_path` which will allow Capybara to default the hostname to localhost - or update your test environment config so the url helpers produce the urls you expect.

Comment: Right on both counts.  The `default_driver` vs `current_driver` issue was just a dumb  mistake on my part.  I would have never figured out the `posts_url` vs `posts_path` mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Capybara `app_host` config eg `Capybara.app_host = ...`. See full docs [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.configure)

Generally, you set Capybara config inside `spec_helper.rb` so that it's enabled in all specs eg:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
  config.app_host   = ...
end
```

Hope that answers your questions?

Comment: `app_host` won't do anything since the user is visiting full urls (as opposed to paths) which will overwrite the hostname anyway, and setting the current driver in the configure block won't do anything in the default configuration because `current_driver` is reset to `default_driver` at the beginning of every test.

Comment: How do I know what the host and port are?  I assume Capybara is launching the rails server.  What methods do I call to query which port was used?

Comment: @Zack `Capybara.current_session.server.port` should be the port once the server is started, or you can fix it by setting `Capybara.server_port`, or you can set `Capybara.always_include_port = true` to have Capybara always insert the port into urls where no specific port is provided.